# Timer trigger before interval

Tags: c#, timer

I have something like the following:

```
myTimer.Interval = 100;  
myTimer.Start();
...
```

In my `myTimer_Elapsed(...)` function something like the following:

`DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString("g")` written to a file.

**Getting this as result:**

System Time Now: 13:20:00,2959841
System Time Now: 13:20:00,3467621
System Time Now: 13:20:00,3789866
System Time Now: 13:20:00,4033991
System Time Now: 13:20:00,4356236
System Time Now: 13:20:00,4619891

I was expecting results bigger than 0,1 seconds because there are more process, and I was trying to calculate that impact, but I'm frustated because I don't know how can be even possible to have times lower than 0,1 seconds

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm struggling to see a problem here, you want your application to be *slower*?

Comment: I think that OP wants the `Timer` to be more accurate. However AFAIK such accuracy can be achieved only by advanced timers.

Comment: The results look relatively accurate to me given the time interval. The OP doesn't really mention which timer they are using, they could already be using an advanced one.

Comment: So you say you have several processes. Maybe they access `myTimer_Elapsed()` more than you expect?

Comment: The issue looks like the timer is running too frequently (it shouldn't be scheduled more frequently than 100ms). Are you sure that you have a) only one timer and b) haven't subscribed to the elapsed event more than once?

Comment: There is only one call in the whole program to myTimer_Elapsed, and I use system.Timers.Timer. The only thing I can think to explain this is that the process start over when another process take the CPU from it. I'm using the system time and comparing the number of steps that should be so far and the number of steps that I have taken. But I keep being unable to explain that result.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of timer do you use? If it's the Windows.Forms.Timer, it has a very limited accuracy .

> The Windows Forms Timer component is single-threaded, and is limited
>   to an accuracy of 55 milliseconds. If you require a multithreaded
>   timer with greater accuracy, use the Timer class in the System.Timers
>   namespace.

Quoted from here: [Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)